# How to do this sql statement using Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models as follows:

```
 icon.rb

  belongs_to :category

  attr_accessible :name, :url, :category_id, :icon_for

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: icons
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  url         :string(255)
#  category_id :integer
#  icon_for    :string(255)
```

category.rb

```
  has_many :icons

  attr_accessible :name, :adult
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
```

In the Icons controller

def index

```
@icons = Icon.where(:icon_for => params[:icon_for])
@category_names_for_icons = ???????
```

end

I want to get all the category names for the categories the selected icons are for.

```
category_names = Category.where(:id => @icons.category_id) how to make this a range?
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to extract the category_id from each of your @icons into an array:

```
category_names = Category.where(:id => @icons.map(&:category_id))
```

The Ruby `map` function iterates over an array, and returns an array.  You can think of the `&:category_id` bit as calling the category_id function on each item in the array.